# Is there an equivalent for connexion in nodejs?

Tags: python, javascript, api, node.js

Python has a module called [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which as far as I understand (I am quite newbie about servers) allows the automatic generation of endpoints in Flask starting from an `openapi.yml` file (https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0). This does not require the explicit definition of these endpoints, allowing a fast development, the warranty of sticking to the api documentation, and less verbosity; the only thing needed is to provide a function to be executed whose name corresponds to the `operationId` associated to the endpoint in the `openapi.yml` file.

Being new to this field, I wonder if node.js offers something similar (which I would expect, being it kind of made for the web). Namely, I am looking for a module that can handle implicitly the endpoints reading directly from a openapi specification.

Comment: you may have some luck searching for "nodejs" solutions. javascript is often used on the "frontend" of websites where it is making requests, rather than responding to them through endpoints. node.js may be a better search term if you are looking to use javascript in more of a server-side role and may help you find what you need

Comment: Thanks @DeveloperACE, I will update my question

Comment: The question seemed fine to me, i was thinking more along the lines of if you hapen to be searching online for answers, using "node.js" as a keyword may give you better search results